# urllib, urllib2, urllib.request.open, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am trying using `urllib` but it shows error, version is Python 2, i also tried using `urllib2` and `urllib.request.open()`.

```
import urllib
import sys

print (sys.version)

myurl = urllib.urlopen('http://www.profmcmillan.com')
print (myurl)
```

output:

```
2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
..
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

with urllib2

```
import urllib2
import sys

print (sys.version)

myurl = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.profmcmillan.com')
print (myurl)
```

output:

```
2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
..
    myurl = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.profmcmillan.com')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

same if I import urllib and use urllib.request.open

Comment: what is the name of your file/module? My guess is the default type is being overridden

Comment: What does your `sys.path` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *may* be that you named your file `urllib.py` or you have such a file in your python path. So with:

```
import urllib
```

it doesn't import the real `urllib` library but one of your files. You can check the module file path with:

```
import urllib
print urllib.__file__
```

For example mine refers to: `/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc`

Comment: yep, thats all I could think of. The code is perfect

Comment: Wow, Thanks @enrico that's exactly the problem, how you figured it out :)

Comment: @garg10may Well, it was strange but it was the only possibility :)